# Illustrator Graph Larger than Artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

When I open a new project, I have set my file size to 800w by 500h. I then selected the bar graph and drew a box of approximate size for the graph. This then opened the table box, where I imported my data. I then clicked the checkbox to place the graph data, and it overlaps both the box I drew for the graph and the artboard itself.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The box you draw defines the **data area** and not the data area + label area. Just resize the art after the graph is drawn.

Comment: Thanks - I resized it but was and probably still am confused why it was so large to begin with, but at least I have it the size I need.

Answer (score 1):

to solve the issue you can adjust the artboard to the size of the arts:

"Fit to Artwork Bounds"

[image]